# guildMemberAdd dont work with Jimp | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, discord.js, jimp

This function its not working. I tried a lot of things and nothing,i think its the "guildMemberAdd".

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {

  let canal = client.channels.get(config.welcome)
  let fonte = await jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_32_BLACK)
  let mask = await jimp.read('mascara.png')
  let fundo = await jimp.read('fundo.png')
  
  jimp.read(member.user.displayAvatarURL).then(avatar => {
  avatar.resize(130, 130)
  mask.resize(130, 130)
  avatar.mask(mask)

  fundo.print(fonte, 170, 175, member.user.username)
  fundo.composite(avatar, 40, 90).write('bemvindo.png')
  canal.send(`Welcome !`, { files: ["bemvindo.png"] })
  
  console.log('Imagem enviada para o Discord')
  })
  .catch(err => {
  console.log('error avatar')
  })
});
```

Detail, the bot works, just the jimp part dont work

If someone know why dont work, pls tell me.

Comment: Have you enabled the required intents?

Comment: yes, its already enable

Comment: Do you get any `<UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning>` thrown?

Comment: I didnt change nothing now work, but gives me the error "error avatar", that means the image its created , but he can't send, i check the config file, and discord chat and its both are ok

Comment: @Viriato nothing ;/

Comment: Replace `console.log('error avatar')` with `console.log(err);` and let us know what does it log.

Comment: @Viriato Gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is because you have Discord.js v11 code but you're running the bot with Discord.js v12.

`client.channels.get(config.welcome)` should now be `client.channels.cache.get(config.welcome)`.

Fixed code below:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {

  let canal = await client.channels.fetch(config.welcome)
  let fonte = await jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_32_BLACK)
  let mask = await jimp.read('mascara.png')
  let fundo = await jimp.read('fundo.png')
  
  jimp.read(member.user.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png'})).then(avatar => {
  avatar.resize(130, 130)
  mask.resize(130, 130)
  avatar.mask(mask)

  fundo.print(fonte, 170, 175, member.user.username)
  fundo.composite(avatar, 40, 90).write('bemvindo.png')
  await canal.send(`Welcome !`, { files: ["bemvindo.png"] })
  
  console.log('Imagem enviada para o Discord')
  })
  .catch(err => {
  console.log('error avatar')
  })
});
```

Comment: i using discord "discord.js": "^12.0.0", that means discord v12 :/

Comment: anf if i put "client.channels.cache.get" gives me error of jimp ```Error: No matching constructor overloading was found.```

Comment: Can you try upgrading to Discord.js v12.5.3?

Comment: same error ```No matching constructor overloading was found```

Comment: I realized my error, there were supposed to be parentheses after `displayAvatarUrl`. The code should be fixed and should work now.

Comment: It wasn't working since in Discord.js v12 `displayAvatarURL` is now a function. Because your code didn't have parentheses, it wasn't returning a valid URL, so Jimp was returning an error.

Comment: That error its fixed, but now i have another, i change "console.log('error avatar') to console.log(err) , and now gives me Error: Unsupported MIME type: image/webp , all file are .png and i could find anything ;(

Comment: Set display format to PNG, you should be good to go on that issue now...

Comment: Now gives me 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined' 
Here its my full code "index,js only" 
https://ghostbin.com/paste/7H2tN